# How can I read metadata from .slx file with C#?

Tags: c#, matlab, simulink

I am working with MATLAB. When I create .slx model and use next MATLAB code for insert metadata.

```
`h = load_system(pathToFile);
set_param(h, 'Metadata', properties)`
```

MATLAB write my data in .mxarray file in .slx.
How can read metadata of .slx file or from .mxarray with C#.